# Data requested with ajax always the same

Tags: php, ajax, caching, jquery

There must be some kind of server side cache on my server...

Every time when I am requesting content using jquery ajax i get the same data, even if I replace server side code with

```
echo('hello, world!');
```

Used configuration:

- SuSE Linux
- Apache Server
- PHP 5

**What kind of caching could be active?**

As you can see, I have implemented two codes to prevent browser caching within the javascript below. The problem is definitely on the server side.

**Just for information:**

Client side code:

```
// Add a timestamp to url to prevent browser from caching ajax content
var date = new Date();
var timestamp = date.getTime();
var nocache = '&nocache=' + timestamp;

// Ajax call: get entries, add to entries div
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jsfeed.php",
    //data: "lastmsg="+ ID,
    data: "<?php echo("key=$api_key&fc=$collection_ident&offset="); ?>" + (ID+1) + "<?php echo("&showmax=$showmax&nocontainer" . $jstaggedonly); ?>" + nocache,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $("div#updates").append(html);
        $("#more"+ID).remove();
    }
});
```

Server side code:

```
if( isSet($_POST['offset']) && isSet($_POST['showmax']) )
{
  $offset  = $_POST['offset'];
  $showmax = $_POST['showmax'];
  $new_offset = $offset + $showmax;

  $call = $api_url . 'jsfeed.php?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

  $html = file_get_contents($call);
  echo($html);
  // ...
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to [have a look](http://feeds.jay-systems.com/web/browser.php?key=208f810275abc96f356920a2a40273ed&fc=updates) - the page where I'm testing (online for a limited time)...  Search for a "Show more" button below updates list. This is where the ajax call is triggered.

**Edit:**

I solved this. There was an error in my script. There is no need to append a timestamp manually, like I did above. jQuery option `cache: false` is enough. So, it just looks like this:

```
// Ajax call: get entries, add to entries div
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jsfeed.php",
    data: "<?php echo("key=$api_key&fc=$collection_ident&offset="); ?>" + (ID+1) + "<?php echo("&showmax=$showmax&nocontainer" . $jstaggedonly); ?>",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $("div#updates").append(html);
        $("#more"+ID).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: A very simple test is to just replace `"jsfeed.php"` with `"jsfeed.php?" + Math.random()`... that will disable any cache for sure. If it is still happening, make sure you are actually requesting from the file you think you are requesting from.

Comment: Just tested this, but I'm still getting the same records. I just added a link above, where you can see it. Look for a "Show more" button. I just tried to get echo('Hello!'); Unfortunately no luck.

Comment: I checked now and I don't see "Hello!", did you change it back? Still, if the cache is involved, do a CTRL-F5 and it really really shouldn't be anymore. Anyway, it's hard for us to debug since we can't add new items (thus checking to see if it's the same).

Comment: Yes, as a sayed... Hello! should come, but posting entries are displayed. The only code effective in server php is now: echo('Hello!'); exit();

Comment: Then we are not looking at the same page, I looked at your code, got the link to jsfeed.php and put it in the browser, and indeed it's the same as displayed by AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers extremely aggressively cache AJAX requests if not explicitly told not to by the server.

Try something like (taken from the php manual, php.net/headers):

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Comment: It's a POST-request though, they must never be cached really.

Comment: Well, it apparently is being cached :).  I've seen IE 8 and 9 cache all kinds of things that they shouldn't.  (No idea if he's using IE though.)

Comment: @Corbin: Tested my scripts using Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the timestamp to the url and not the data sent..

```
var nocache = '?nocache=' + timestamp;
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jsfeed.php" + nocache,
```

Comment: That's what the `cache: false` property in `$.ajax` is for - it appends a timestamp automatically.